# Scrabble Board Tiles in Android

Tags: android

i'm very new to android and i don't know much about the attributes that android uses.for my scrabble game board, i decided that i'll use an image of
an actual game board. i was thinking that i'll use a gridview for the board tiles.

i just wanna ask if it's possible to split the image into a 15 x 15 board that i can use? like i can put a specific code for each triple word, double letter, etc. values each tile contain?

thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the image as a background of the parent layout (the wrapper of the gridview). Then add the GridView as a child with a Translucent theme. Something like:

```
gridview.setAlpha(alpha)
```

This way you won't have to crop the image into pieces.

Haven't tried it. It's just a suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create 15 * 15 = 225 tiles (you won't have to manually create it of course, just copy paste) and then give each tile a name in matrix format like the first tile as a00, second (in first line) as a01 etc. and then when working on their cell values, create a variable initiated as 'a' and add the matrix number of the tile you want to go to (like a + '0' + '1') and use this variable as the id of the tile you want to work on.